# Using pdb in emacs inserts => into my code

Tags: python, emacs, pdb

I'm trying to learn how to use pdb in emacs.

I run emacs in console mode and in my python file I have something like `import pdb` and `pdb.set_trace()` at the beginning of the file. I use `C-c C-c` to execute the buffer and pdb starts running. It works fine except that I end up with a `=>` inserted into my code on the line that pdb is looking at. When pdb ends, the `=>` characters remain in my code on the last line and I have to manually delete it. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally there is no "=>" inserted at all.  What there is instead is a "=>" that is *displayed* but which is not part of the buffer's content.  Are you sure it's really in the code and are you sure you can delete it as if it were normal text?

Comment: Yes! It's actually text! And I have to position my cursor there and backspace on it to delete the two characters `=`, and `>`. I'm using console mode (starting emacs as `emacs -nw`)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the the pdb support of your python-mode, then.

Comment: This is the official binary for windows :(

Comment: Not sure in which way this makes a difference.  If you want a bug fixed, you need to report it, e.g. via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.